# Offline Voice-to-Text Now Showing Up?

Tags: voice-recognition

I am seeing many articles pointing to how to setup Android Voice-to-Text offline, but I am not seething the setting where they tell me to look (languages & Input).

Has the location changed, has it been removed? Does my phone just not have the capability?

Works online.

Android 8.1.0 - June 5, 2018
PRO_SELFIE - SKY_Pro-Selfie_V06_20180625

Answer (score 0):

In Settings -> Languages & input, tap on Virtual keyboard, then Google voice typing. Tap on "Offline speech recognition", then All. Select the language(s) that should be downloaded and use offline.

Alternatively, if you have Gboard installed, in Settings -> Languages & input, tap on Virtual keyboard, then Gboard. Click on Voice typing, then "Offline speech recognition". Click on "Offline speech recognition", then All. Select the language(s) that should be downloaded and use offline.